# Windows login sound does not play although the check mark is ticked in sound settings

Tags: windows, system-sounds

I'm having trouble with my new laptop, the IdeaPad 3 15ITL6. Even though I have enabled the Windows login sound in my settings, it doesn't play when I log in. Can you help me resolve this issue?